# For any integer $a$, $\gcd(11a+5,2a+1)=1$.

Tags: divisibility

How would I go by proving this statement?

What I did was I tried using Proposition GCD Of One, so that

$(11a+5)x + (2a+1)y = 1$, and
$(11x+2y)a + (5x+y) = 1$.

But I have no idea what to do from here.
What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Can you justify the following?

\begin{align*}
\gcd(11a + 5, 2a + 1) &= \gcd\Big((11a + 5) - 5(2a + 1), 2a + 1\Big) \\
&= \gcd(a, 2a + 1)
\end{align*}

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain how the first line works?

Comment: @Haxify $$\gcd(a, c) = \gcd(a - c, c)$$

Comment: Oh, okay I see how that works. Thank you!

Comment: Then is it correct to say that $\gcd(11a+5,2a+1)=\gcd(a,2a+1)=\gcd(1,a)$?

Comment: @Haxify Exactly.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,d\,$ is a common factor then $\,{\rm mod}\ d\!:\ 2a+1\equiv 0\equiv 11a+5.\,$ Now  **eliminate** $\,a\,$ by cross multiplying  $\ 0\equiv \color{#0a0}{11}(2a+1)-\color{#c00}2(11a+5) \equiv \color{#0a0}{11}-\color{#c00}{10}\equiv 1\ $ i.e. $\,0\equiv 1,\,$ so $\, d\mid 1\!-\!0,\,$ so $\,d = 1.$

**Remark** $\ $ *More conceptually,* put the *fractions* for $\,-a\,$ over the common denominator $\,22$

$$ {\rm mod}\ d\!:\ \  \frac{1}{2} \equiv -a\,\equiv \frac{5}{11}\ \Rightarrow\ \frac{\color{#0a0}{11}}{22}\,\equiv\, \frac{\color{#c00}{10}}{22}\qquad$$

**Note** $ $ The fractions uniquely exist mod $\,d\,$ since $\,2,11\,$ are invertible, being coprime to $\,d\,$ (else $2\mid d\mid 2a+1\,\Rightarrow 2\mid 1,\,$ and $\,11\mid d\mid 11a+5\,\Rightarrow\, 11\mid 5\,)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!!