# GCDs of two expression is one of the expression itself

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Given integer constants $a,b,d$ ($a,b$ are coprime) and an integer variable $x$, is there a way to easily find for which $x$ does $gcd(a^2-db^2,a-bx)=a^2-db^2$ without substituting the values of $x$ individually and calculating the gcd? This is a continuation oy my gcd studies following the link [Relation between two gcds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699592/relation-between-two-gcds).

Thanks

Comment: As in prior\ question: let $\,e = a^2-db^2.\,$ Then $\,(e,b) = (a^2,b)=1\,$ by $\,(a,b)=1,\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{b^{-1}}$ exists $\bmod e.\,$

$\,(e,a-bx) = e\iff e\mid a-bx\iff x\equiv a\color{#c00}{b^{-1}}\pmod{e}\ \ $